# Change the width of animated input in w3 css

Tags: w3.css

I used animated input from W3 CSS. It takes 100% of the width when I click on it, but I only want it to take up 75% of the width when I click on it.

The code is:

```
<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-animate-input" type="text" style="width:30%">
```

Comment: are you sure it's the whole code that enabled animation? I've tried a fiddle and I can see no animation: https://jsfiddle.net/jajzghj3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property you are trying to change is controlled by a **pseudo-class**. You need to change the width of `w3-animate-input:focus {width:75%;}`. You must add this to your code. You can add this to

- the head section of your page between `<script>` tag.
- the w3.css file if you are hosting it on your website.

Comment: I dont have w3.css. So i put it in <script></script> and it work. Thank you.